# Select DropDown List element using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: scala, selenium

So i have this DropDown List with several items and i want to select 
specicifc one:

```
val dropDownList = driver.fineElement...

val javascriptExecutor: JavascriptExecutor = driver.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]

javascriptExecutor.executeScript("$('li.bla-bla span:contains(\"myValue\")').parent().click()", dropDownList)
```

So my problem is that this is selected all the elements that contains `myValue`, how can i select only exactly the one that i want ?

Answer (score 0):

what language you using.

here is a python example

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
 Select(driver.find_element_by_id("p3")).select_by_visible_text("XXXX")
```

You can use the xpath to locate the element then select it

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"XXXX")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium's Select class

```
Select select= new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByValue("value");
```

There's an explanation here: http://forum.testproject.io/index.php?topic=42.0